# Python super usage example

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python docs for super say: **Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type**

`super(type[, object-or-type])`

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super

Can someone give me a `super` example where method calls are delegated to sibling class of type?

Comment: [Raymond Hettinger can](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). For a while that was the first thing that came up on Google if you searching for "python super", but now it's down to #6, behind a couple of much worse blog posts and an SO answer that's mostly links without explanation…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using a triangle inheritence pattern:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print 'A.__init__()'
...         super(A, self).__init__()
... 
>>> class B(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print 'B.__init__()'
...         super(B, self).__init__()
... 
>>> class C(A, B):
...     def __init__(self):
...         print 'C.__init__()'
...         super(C, self).__init__()
... 
>>> C()
C.__init__()
A.__init__()
B.__init__()
<__main__.C object at 0x10f27e190>
```

Here `super(A, self).__init__()` inside of `A.__init__()` called `B.__init__()`, a sibling class.

`super()` looks at the classes in the MRO (method resolution order) on `self`, locates where the first argument is located in that order, and returns the requested method on the next class after that. For `C`, the MRO is:

```
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>)
```

so `super(A, self)` looks for methods on `B` and on `object`.

Comment: If anyone wants deeper details, see [Python's super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)—which has some real-life examples instead of abstract toy examples—and [The Python 2.3 Method Resolution Order](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)—which explains exactly how it works and why it works that way.